# How do I sign Jars when exporting an Eclipse RCP product?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

My team develops an Eclipse RCP application, and we want to sign our jars when the product is exported, but we didn't find a way to do this.  Interface-wise, jars signing is available only through features and plugins export commands, not through product export.

So far, we tried to add signing information on our plugins build.properties files and on some of the files located on eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build\scripts.  Nothing changed and our plugins were still unsigned.

We understand that we have to use Ant instructions to achieve that, but we don't know neither how or where we do it.

How do I sign Jars when exporting an Eclipse RCP product?

Comment: PDE Build has been deprecated for a couple of years now. Nowadays you build your Eclipse plugin via Maven/Tycho: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#signing-plug-ins

Comment: When it comes to building a whole RCP Application, does the same idea apply?  I mean, we have a .product file, and on its Eclipse editor, we just click on the "Export product" do build it.  Should we do something different in this case?

Comment: @howlger Ok.. the PDE Build is no longer used. But, how do people did the sign process back then, when PDE Build was the main choice?

Comment: @JoseRenato That is now so many years ago ... but if you're really interested, see how Eclipse did it.

Comment: @MarioMarinato Yes, nowadays Tycho is the way to go. It's just running a Maven build, which you can do locally in your IDE or even better by a continuous integration server. See mentioned tutorial with its [example repo](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example).

Comment: @howlger  Ok, thanks.  It bugs me that Eclipse still provides the old "Export product" command, when there are better options available, but it might be due to compatibility issues.  I'll check into the tutorial.  Thanks.

Comment: Change happen. And the next thing will be signing with PGP https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MnDBvOUwKvKacB-QKnH_PzK88dUlHkjs-D-DWEKmvkY ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the documentation.
There it is described very well, including examples.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  We have seen that, but we didn't find a way to make it work when we export the Eclipse product.